# Chef cookbooks to set up a Rails production server (CentOS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, chef-solo

So, I got tired of seting up production servers for my Rails apps all the time and decided to learn to use a tool that can simplify that process for me. I choose Chef-solo. 
I've read the documentation and watched some tutorials, but I'm not realy sure I understend the process well, so I decided to go right to practice and learn on the way.

Now the real question: can someone provide me with a set of correctly working cookbooks to set up the server so I wouldn't need to reinvent the wheel myself?

OS - CentOS  v.6.0-6.3

Software:

- Development Tools (groupinstall)
- git
- Node.js
- ImageMagick
- Nginx and Unicorn
- MySQL and PosgreSQL
- Mail Server POP/SMTP/IMAP
- RVM + ruby
- MemCache

Think that's it.
Ofcource I need not only to install the packages, but also to configure them properly.
Any suggestions or additional info needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try looking at my repo at https://github.com/dmytro/chef-solo

I am using it to bootstrap Rails environments for myself.

Additionally it can be combined with Capistrano deployment. I use this in my capistrano recipes https://github.com/dmytro/capistrano-recipes

I've put blog post on these. Please lake a look too: http://dmytro.github.io/2013/05/21/easy_spawn_new_hosts_with_capistrano.html